# How to read content from application specific binary files in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to read a binary file's contents using C#. Consider an application that can have files that are specific to the application, meaning users can open these files using only this application. The application may not give full access to a user, e.g., a certain user may be granted read-only access. Say I want to allow a certain user to open a file associated with my application and allow the user to edit the file. I have tried the following:

```
// Read the file into <bits>
var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.appx", FileMode.Open);
var len = (int)fs.Length;
var bits = new byte[len];
fs.Read(bits, 0, len);
// Dump 16 bytes per line
for (int ix = 0; ix < len; ix += 16) 
{
    var cnt = Math.Min(16, len - ix);
    var line = new byte[cnt];
    Array.Copy(bits, ix, line, 0, cnt);
    // Write address + hex + ascii
    Console.Write("{0:X6}  ", ix);
    Console.Write(BitConverter.ToString(line));
    Console.Write("  ");
    // Convert non-ascii characters to .
    for (int jx = 0; jx < cnt; ++jx)
        if (line[jx] < 0x20 || line[jx] > 0x7f) line[jx] = (byte)'.';
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(line));
}
```

However, I am not able to read the data from the application-specific binary file. Is there any other way that I can read the complete file contents?

**I Updated my Question :**

d        ÿþÿ5C 
: **\ U S E R S \ 
V S   T E C H N 
O S \ D E S K T 
O P \ T R A I N 
I N G \ R A W \ 
1 \ S E C - 3 5 
. X P R**  ÿÿ
CProfileÿþÿ
   ²    çÂu°
º£ì?         €AÀ
          :

: §èH.
ÿ¡!ÀåÐ"ÛùÞ.À
 €AÀZd;ßOí ÀTã¥›
Ä -À     €AÀ¨WÊ2
Ä1 ÀÚ¬ú\me+À
 €AÀHPüs×ÀÊTÁ¨
¤®)À     €AÀÄB­i
Þ1À®¶bÙý'À
 €AÀ°çŒ(mÀ0»'
U&À     €AÀ¿}8
g„ÀƒÀÊ¡E¶$À
 €AÀÁÊ¡E¶sÀNÑ‘\
þ##À     €AÀd]ÜF

i am able to read some text in human readable format and i can't remaining text which is like corrupted data.

Comment: What is the difference about the binary content and a simple txt file?

Comment: i mean, when i read the file it is giving data in unknown language. like a corrupted data.

Comment: How is it corrupted?  Big-endian vs little-endian?

Comment: It looks like you are just trying to print out a `.appx` file. Did you know those files are actually renamed zip files and you must decompress them first?

Comment: Without a description of the file format you are most likely out of luck - the "permission" bit or byte could be stored anywhere. You have a good chance trying to reverse engineer this though by comparing new files that can be edited to files that are locked for editing. What is the difference in the binary? Go from there.

Comment: If you want to reverse-engineer the binary format of some app files, then the path of trial and errors awaits you... So just try to find the specification of those files.

Comment: As per @ScottChamberlain - this seems to be the file format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163372.aspx

Comment: @KarthikBammidi, I can help you to read txt file line by line, would it be helpful?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to read some other application's files or you're trying to make an application like that?

Comment: @T.S. I am trying to read some other application's file form my application.

Comment: Oh, you will need to know how it writes the file, its structure. Do you know it?

Comment: @T.S. I don't know how it was created. I want to be able to see its content in human readable format.

Comment: You will have to spend many hours. Basically, do what hackers do. Try different things. Data could be just binary serialized object or a stream, or something else. Best what you can do is first, reverse engineer code from that other application and find how it saves the file. If this is .net application - that should be easy. When you know how file is composed, you can start working on your program.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and VERY dirty version. I did this with a small binary file I have, and it worked perfectly.

```
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);   
//Your byte array stuff, turn it from Binary to Byte array into memory aka byteArray

... //MORE STATEMENTS ETC....

//Reads your byteArray as a readable txt File that will allow them to read it accordingly in ENGLISH.

string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)
```